# How can I filter out just one ocurrence in a string vector in Scala?

Tags: scala

I need to create a new vector from `Vector("lumber", "stone", "magic potion","stone","lumber")` but without the string `"lumber"`, if i use the method `filterNot(_=="lumber")` it removes the two elements that match `"lumber"`. is there a filter out just one ocurrence?

i tried using `.distinct` but i need the two stones in the vector.

Comment: I would guess the simplest solution wold be to use a little bit of mutable state so you keep track if you already filtered or not. Other option would be to use `List` instead and write your own recursive function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to use diff:

```
val c = Vector("lumber", "stone", "magic potion","stone","lumber")
c diff Vector("lumber")
// result: Vector(stone, magic potion, stone, lumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the collection at the first occurence and then drop it:

```
val (pre, post) = c.span(_ == "lumber")
pre.dropRight(1) ++ post
```

When there is no "lumber" in the collection, `pre` will be empty and `pre.dropRight(1)` will drop nothing.

With 2.13 you can prefer a one-liner using `pipe`:

```
import scala.util.chaining._

c.span(_ == "lumber").pipe(split => split._1.dropRight(1) ++ split._2)
```